# How to iterate over a sparse matrix with condition in Python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, exponential, indicator, exp

I have a matrix with only 0 and 1 and it works as the indicator. Now I would like to replace the element of the matrix with value of 5 to the power of the original element. (Python please)

For example, if:
**old element = 0 -> new element is 5^0 = 1**; else
**old element = 1 -> new element is 5^1 = 5**

**INPUT:**

```
0 1 0
0 1 1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 5 1
1 5 5
```

Please help this is urgent for my thesis code and this is also my first (real) time posting a question. I am trying to find power function or exponential package but it is not the one I need.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's stopping you from iterating over every single element? Do you have a class that can store matrices already?

Comment: Hi, this is just an example, my data set is 1500 data points with like 20x150 marrix, I am not sure how to do with the index, can you please specify? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate (in python code), just use your 0/1 array as index

```
 arr = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
 new = np.array([1,5])[arr]
```

Comment: Hi, this is just an example, my data set is 1500 data points, I am not sure how to do with the index, can you please specify? Thank you!

Comment: This will work with a (20,150) array of 0/1 just as well with this (2,3).  Have you tried it?